# How to stop loop until user inputs a keyword to stop?

Tags: python

My code right now is in an infinite loop, displaying the menu choices for doughnuts. I want it so that the user selects as many doughnuts as they want until they input "5".

Here is my code:

```
print("Welcome to Dino's International Doughnut Shoppe!")
name = input("Please enter your name to begin: ")

#doughnuts menu
loop = 0
while loop == 0:
    choice = 0
    while choice not in [1,2,3,4]:
        print("Please enter a valid choice from 1-4.")
        print("Please select a doughnut from the following menu: ")
        print("1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)")
        print("2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)")
        print("3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)")
        print("4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)")
        print("5. No more doughnuts.")
        choice = int(input(">"))


if choice == 1:
    chocolate = int(input("How many chocolate-dipped Maple Puff(s) would you like to purchase? "))
elif choice == 2:
    strawberry = int(input("How many Strawberry Twizzler(s) would you like to purchase? "))
elif choice == 3:
    vanilla = int(input("How many Vanilla Chai Strudel(s) would you like to purchase? "))
elif choice == 4:
    honey = int(input("How many Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie(s) would you like to purchase? "))
elif choice == 5:
    print(f"{name}, Here is your receipt: ")

    if choice == 1:
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"{chocolate} Chocolate Dipped Maple Puffs")
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"Total Cost: ${chocolate*3.50:.2f}")
    elif choice == 2:
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"{strawberry} Strawberry Twizzlers")
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"Total Cost: ${strawberry*2.25:.2f}")
    elif choice == 3:
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"{vanilla} Vanilla Chai Strudels")
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"Total Cost: ${vanilla*4.05:.2f}")
    elif choice == 4:
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"{honey} Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchies")
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"Total Cost: ${honey*1.99:.2f}")

print("Thank you for shopping at Dino's International Doughnut Shoppe! Please come again!")
```

So right now the code only displays the doughnuts menu continuously, but I want it so when 5 is inputted, it would go to the math calculation/end of the code.

Comment: The while loop == 0 is always true because loop never changes. Fix that while loop.

Comment: Yeah, I am still new to python... still having problems understanding what you mean. How would I make it so the loop changes? Something to do with the initialization?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems here.

The first is that the logic to respond to a choice is outside your `while` loops. That can be fixed by indenting that whole block.

Second when the user inputs `5`, the condition in `while choice not in [1,2,3,4]:` evaluates to `True`, so the user is prompted to enter a valid choice again. This can be fixed by removing that inner `while` loop entirely.

Finally upon reaching the `elif choice == 5` block, the user will not see any of these receipt prints because `choice` is `5` and therefore not `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`. I think what you mean here is for the count of `chocolate`, `strawberry`, `vanilla`, or `honey` to be nonzero. Also these should all be `if` rather than `elif` blocks since they are independent of each other (a user can get some chocolate and some vanilla).

With all that in mind here is a refactor:

```
print("Welcome to Dino's International Doughnut Shoppe!")
name = input("Please enter your name to begin: ")

#doughnuts menu
chocolate = strawberry = vanilla = honey = 0
done = False
while not done:
    print("Please enter a valid choice from 1-4.")
    print("Please select a doughnut from the following menu: ")
    print("1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)")
    print("2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)")
    print("3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)")
    print("4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)")
    print("5. No more doughnuts.")
    choice = int(input(">"))


    if choice == 1:
        chocolate = int(input("How many chocolate-dipped Maple Puff(s) would you like to purchase? "))
    elif choice == 2:
        strawberry = int(input("How many Strawberry Twizzler(s) would you like to purchase? "))
    elif choice == 3:
        vanilla = int(input("How many Vanilla Chai Strudel(s) would you like to purchase? "))
    elif choice == 4:
        honey = int(input("How many Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie(s) would you like to purchase? "))
    elif choice == 5:
        done = True
        print(f"{name}, Here is your receipt: ")

        if chocolate > 1:
            print("==========================================")
            print(f"{chocolate} Chocolate Dipped Maple Puffs")
            print("==========================================")
            print(f"Total Cost: ${chocolate*3.50:.2f}")
        if strawberry > 1:
            print("==========================================")
            print(f"{strawberry} Strawberry Twizzlers")
            print("==========================================")
            print(f"Total Cost: ${strawberry*2.25:.2f}")
        if vanilla > 1:
            print("==========================================")
            print(f"{vanilla} Vanilla Chai Strudels")
            print("==========================================")
            print(f"Total Cost: ${vanilla*4.05:.2f}")
        if honey > 1:
            print("==========================================")
            print(f"{honey} Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchies")
            print("==========================================")
            print(f"Total Cost: ${honey*1.99:.2f}")

    print("Thank you for shopping at Dino's International Doughnut Shoppe! Please come again!")
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** check the improved version at the bottom of the answer

You can use the [second form of `iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to conveniently loop over user input until a certain value is given, in that case `5`.

```
def get_choice():
    while True:
        choice = input('> ')
        if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'):
            return int(choice)
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid choice from 1-5.")

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    print("Please select doughnuts from the following menu: ")
    print("1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)")
    print("2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)")
    print("3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)")
    print("4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)")
    print("5. No more doughnuts.")

    order = set(iter(get_choice, 5))

    print(order)
```

### Example

```
Please select doughnuts from the following menu: 
1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.50 each)
2. Strawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)
3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)
4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99)
5. No more doughnuts.
> 2
> 4
> 3
> 7
Please enter a valid choice from 1-5.
> 5
{2, 3, 4}
```

As you can see, this generated a `set` of orders which can then be used to request further inputs.

## Use data structures

Although, using a bunch of elif statements is not optimal here because it adds a lot of repetition and is not very maintainable. Instead, you should use a list of dictionaries to store information specific to each donut.

```
    doughnuts = [
        {'name': 'Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff', 'price': 3.50},
        {'name': 'Stawberry Twizzler', 'price': 2.25},
        ...
    ]
```

Now, all the `print` above can be simplified like so.

```
    for i, doughnut in enumerate(doughnuts, start=1):
        print(f'{i}. {doughnut["name"]} (${doughnut["price"]} each)')
    print(f'{i + 1}. No more doughnuts.')
```

You should do the same for you arithmetic, when variable are highly related, their values should instead be stored together in a `list` or a `dict`.

```
receipt = [
    {
        **doughnuts[i],
        'qty': int(input(f'How many {doughnuts[i]["name"]} '))
    }
    for i in order
]

print(f"Here is your receipt: ")

for item in receipt:
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"{item['qty']} {item['name']}")
    print("==========================================")
    print(f"Total Cost: ${item['qty'] * item['price']:.2f}")
```

### Example

```
1. Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff ($3.5 each)
2. Stawberry Twizzler ($2.25 each)
3. Vanilla Chai Strudel ($4.05 each)
4. Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie ($1.99 each)
5. No more doughnuts.
> 1
> 2
> 5
How many Stawberry Twizzler 2
How many Vanilla Chai Strudel 1
Here is your receipt: 
==========================================
2 Stawberry Twizzler
==========================================
Total Cost: $4.50
==========================================
1 Vanilla Chai Strudel
==========================================
Total Cost: $4.05
```

## Final version

You then have a simplified version of you code. Shorter and more easy to maintain: to add doughnuts you simply need to update the initial list `doughnuts`.

```
doughnuts = [
    {'name': 'Chocolate-dipped Maple Puff', 'price': 3.50},
    {'name': 'Stawberry Twizzler', 'price': 2.25},
    {'name': 'Vanilla Chai Strudel', 'price': 4.05},
    {'name': 'Honey-drizzled Lemon Dutchie', 'price': 1.99}
]

def get_choice():
    allowed = map(str, range(1, len(doughnuts) + 2))
    while True:
        choice = input('> ')
        if choice in allowed:
            return int(choice)
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid choice.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i, doughnut in enumerate(doughnuts, start=1):
        print(f'{i}. {doughnut["name"]} (${doughnut["price"]} each)')
    print(f'{i + 1}. No more doughnuts.')

    receipt = [
        {
            **doughnuts[i],
            'qty': int(input(f'How many {doughnuts[i]["name"]}'))
        }
        for i in set(iter(get_choice, 5))
    ]

    print(f"Here is your receipt: ")
    for item in receipt:
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"{item['qty']} {item['name']}")
        print("==========================================")
        print(f"Total Cost: ${item['qty'] * item['price']:.2f}")
```